# Can I match a set negatively in nftables?

Tags: nftables

Let's say I want to apply a rule to `ip daddr { 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16 }`, but I want to exclude two more specific IPv4 addresses from that. How do I do that?

I was hoping for some more elegant way of doing this:

```
ip daddr { 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16 } \
  ip daddr != 10.0.1.2 \
  ip daddr != 10.0.2.3
```

as explained in the `nft` manpage for negation of addresses or ranges, but it does not show a way to do that with *sets*.

Comment: If someone comes across this - there is a great in-depth documentation for the 'libnftables' library: https://www.mankier.com/5/libnftables-json#Statements-Match \- AnsibleGuy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that negations of sets are working as expected (undocumented):

```
ip daddr { 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16 } \
  ip daddr != { 10.0.1.2, 10.0.2.3 }
```